# How to use an ostringstream in just an expression

Tags: c++, ostringstream

I use `std::ostringstream` for formatting strings, which inherits its `<<` operators from `ostream`, and consequently they return an `ostream` and not an `ostringstream`, which means that I can't call `ostringstream::str` on the result. This usually isn't a problem, since I can typically do this:

```
ostringstream stream;
stream << whatever;
string str = stream.str();
```

But occasionally I need* to use it in just a single expression, which is more difficult. I could do

```
string str = ((ostringstream&) (ostringstream() << whatever)).str();
```

but bad things will happen if that `<<` overload returns some `ostream` that isn't an `ostringstream`. The only other thing I can think to do is something like

```
string str = ([&] () -> string {ostringstream stream; stream << whatever; return stream.str();})();
```

but this can't possibly be efficient, and is certainly very bad c++ code.

---

*Okay, I don't *need* to, but it would be a lot more convenient to.

Comment: If that overload returned something other than the stream it was given, I would consider it completely broken and throw it away.

Comment: @molbdnilo Unless `whatever` was (or included) a manipulator that was supposed to do that for some reason.

Comment: @Justin That being an idiom says something unflattering about the language.

Comment: @Anonymous Manipulators changing the stream object being acted on sounds pretty broken still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The only other thing I can think to do is something like
>
> ```
> string str = ([&] () -> string {ostringstream stream; stream << whatever; return stream.str();})();
> ```
>
> but this can't possibly be efficient, and is certainly very bad c++
>   code.

Actually, no. Once the optimizer has a look at this, it's exactly as fast as the original code. And it's not "very bad c++ code". It's known as an Immediately Invoked Lambda Expression, or IILE. It's an idiom, and actually quite decent practice.

It would be better formatted more like this, though:

```
// One of the benefits of IILEs is that `const` can be used more frequently
string const str = [&] {
    ostringstream stream;
    stream << whatever;
    return stream.str();
}();
```

Some people prefer using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) to invoke the lambda instead:

```
string const str = std::invoke([&] {
    ostringstream stream;
    stream << whatever;
    return stream.str();
});
```

Comment: I think you should mention that std::invoke is c++17

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
string str = ([&] () -> string
             {
               ostringstream stream;
               stream << whatever;
               return stream.str();
              })();
```

is ok. However, I think it will be better to name that operation, create a function with that name, and call the function.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    template <typename T>
    std::string to_string(T const& t)
    {
        ostringstream stream;
        stream << t;
        return stream.str();
    }
}
```

and then use

```
string str = MyApp::to_string(whatever);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got

```
std::string get_str(std::ostream& out) {
    retrun static_cast<std::stringbuf*>(out.rdbuf())->str();
}
```

You could use

```
std:: string s = get_str(std::ostringstream{} << ...);
```